Routes giving 404 not found on server but working fine on localhost (NextJs with App router)
using nextUI for the navigation in nextjs application
this the folder structure

here is the layout.tsx

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter, Open_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navigation from "@/ui/navigation";
import {Providers} from "./providers";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const open_sans = Open_Sans({ subsets: ["latin"] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${open_sans.className}`}>
        <Providers>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
        </div>
        {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

here is the navigation file

'use client';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarContent, NavbarItem, NavbarMenuToggle,NavbarMenu, NavbarMenuItem} from "@nextui-org/navbar";
import { Link, Button } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";


interface navigationObject {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    link: string
}

const Navigation = () => {

    const path = usePathname();

    const navigationList: navigationObject[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Payment Methods',
            link: '/payment-methods'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bulk Notification',
            link: '/notification'
        }
    ]

    return (

        <Navbar isBordered isBlurred={false} className="flex justify-start shadow-lg">

            <NavbarContent className="hidden sm:flex gap-4 ml-2">
                {navigationList.map((item: navigationObject) => {
                    return (
                        <NavbarItem key={item.id} isActive={path === item.link ? true : false}>
                            <Link color="foreground" className={path === item.link ? 'text-blue-400' : ''} href={item.link}>{item.title}</Link>
                        </NavbarItem>
                    )
                })}
            </NavbarContent>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navigation;


here the page.tsx of payment-methods
import Image from "next/image";
import payTm from "../../../public/images/paytm_upi.png";
import Header from "@/ui/header";
import { useState } from "react";


const PaymentMethods = () => {
  
    return (
        <div>
            <Header name="Payment Methods" />
            {/* <Image src={payTm} alt="" /> */}
        </div>
   
    )
}

export default PaymentMethods;


the routing is working when running using npm run dev but giving Not Found error after creating build and uploading on server. Also, not working when running the index.html of 'out' folder in browser  (Home page is working but routing gives 404 not found)
